# Set button content in a label (custom control)

Tags: wpf, text

**Instead of voting negative this question, answer to tell me what's wrong!**

I want to set the Button Content in a label in the custom control, because when I use it, the Content property is not visible and the button is empty (no text).

Nocturno, thanks, I'm new in this site, i put C[space]sharp, but my reputation don't allow me to use new tags, so I've deleted this one.

I want to put the Button.Content property in a label in the custom control, because the template replaces the original button design, I use this to save code, and add this buttons without a lot of code.

```
<Button x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="35" d:DesignWidth="273" Content="Button">
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Name="rGridBack" StrokeThickness="1">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4D4D4D" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF404040" Offset="0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
                <Rectangle.Stroke>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4F4F4F" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5B5B5B" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Stroke>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FF1E1E1E" Margin="1,1,1,1" Name="rThickness" />
            <Rectangle Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="rGridTop" StrokeThickness="1">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF68686C" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF474747" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
                <Rectangle.Stroke>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF7F7F7F" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF575757" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Stroke>
            </Rectangle>
   <!--This label is where I want to set the Button.Content property-->
            <Label FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Name="tblckStep1Desc" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <Label.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Color="Black" Direction="330" Opacity="0.7" ShadowDepth="1.5" />
                </Label.Effect>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Button.Content" Value="">
                <Setter Property="Content" TargetName="tblckStep1Desc">
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="rGridTop">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF838383" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF545454" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="rGridTop">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF595959" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF929292" Offset="0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="rGridBack">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF414141" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF565656" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="rThickness">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF181818" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF181818" Offset="0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="rGridTop">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF68686C" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF474747" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="rGridTop">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF7F7F7F" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF575757" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="rGridBack">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF4F4F4F" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF5B5B5B" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="rThickness">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF1E1E1E" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF1E1E1E" Offset="0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="tblckStep1Desc">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF898989" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF898989" Offset="0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="rGridTop">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF313131" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF2E2E2E" Offset="0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="rGridTop">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF1F1F1F" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF1F1F1F" Offset="0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="rGridBack">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF414141" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF565656" Offset="0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="rThickness">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF0C0C0C" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF0C0C0C" Offset="0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

The button is based on Adobe CS5 suite on dialog forms, because a lot of code.

Comment: This question is not clear. You tagged it as C code, but this is not C code. In fact, I don't know what it is. Also, you don't explain how you want to set 'Button Content'. Are you attempting to do it with C code? In that case, what have you tried? Otherwise, just edit that file (whatever it is) in a text editor to change the 'Button Content'. Explain more please.

Comment: @Nocturno It is the Xaml for a WPF UserControl, I am supposing he meant C# and he is wanting to bind the UserControls Content to the Labels Content

Comment: That's the reason why you are getting down votes. I'll change it to C#. More information in the original question would help.

Comment: Nocturno, thanks, I'm new in this site, i put C[space]sharp, but my reputation don't allow me to use new tags, so I've deleted this one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the UserControls DataContext to RelativeSource=(RelativeSource Self}

```
<Button x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         d:DesignHeight="35" d:DesignWidth="273" Content="Button">
```

Then you need to change your Label's Binding to:

```
<Label FontWeight="Normal" Content="{Binding Path=Content}" Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Name="tblckStep1Desc" Padding="0"   VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <Label.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Color="Black" Direction="330" Opacity="0.7" ShadowDepth="1.5" />
    </Label.Effect>
</Label>
```

This will give a result that looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have few experience with C# and WPF, but there's a lot of code in my forms using this button design (each one have the triggers, Grid content and more), this going to help me to save code.